# Check the content of NSString with data in NSArray

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsarray

I have the next problem:

In a UITextField, I need to check if the user inserts an invalid character for the Name, like [ ] { }.

My question is, how can I check the content of the UITextField with one NSArray with the invalid characters inside?

Comment: Does the array contain invalid characters that you want to check against?

Comment: I'm trying to put the invalid characters in a Array but, when I try to put @"\]" the compiler tell me Unknown escape sequence "\]"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I explain what I do to solve the problem. Cause I'm controlling the behavior of a UITextField where I use to the user enter the name and one comment, I make a character set with all characters I allow and I put inside the shouldChangeCharactersInRange Method:

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

```
NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzçñ?!'ABCDEFGHIJKNMLOPQRSTUVWXYZÇÑ-_;:0123456789+*()-/@áàéèíìóòúù"] invertedSet];

NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check single letter input from keyboard on some input politics
you need to use textField delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

You should check if *string* contains in your exception array. If so you return *NO* and symbol doesn't appear on screen.